# Find first class name after click

Tags: jquery

I am looking to toggle the visibility of the first instance of a certain class, but only after the clicked item.

Here is what I have now...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.showContentLink').click(function(){
        $(this).next('.showInfo').toggle();             
    });
    $('.showInfo').hide();
});
```

If I click  `showContentLink` it should find the first `"showInfo"` class  after after the clicked item.

```
<a href="" class="showContentLink">show content</a>
<div class="stuff">some stuff</div>
<div class="stuff">some stuff</div>
<div class="showInfo">Show me</div>


<a href="" class="showContentLink">show content</a>
<div class="stuff">some stuff</div>
<div class="stuff">some stuff</div>
<div class="showInfo">Show me</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.nextAll()`, and narrow down to the first result...

```
$(this).nextAll('.showInfo').first().toggle();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5pNaR/

---

Or `.nextUntil()`, followed by `.last().next()`...

```
$(this).nextUntil('.showInfo').last().next().toggle();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5pNaR/2/

Answer (score 0):

You should consider changing your html, if things are grouped then they should have some property in common, or be contained within some kind of grouping element. However, in the spirit of a challenge, what you're looking for it:

```
$(this).nextAll('.showInfo').first().toggle;
```

[.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) will only grab the very next sibling, never any farther, and then filter with your selector. What you're looking to do is grab ALL the following siblings with [.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/), filtered by a selector, then retain only the first one.

Comment: Thank's for breaking it down.